# How to stop I2C communication when you are recieving a data from slave?

Tags: c, smartcard, i2c, msp430

I am implementing I2C communication protocol. I am sending 5 bytes of data to a slave device (slave address is 0x48). and Then want to see the response.

I am getting my desired response, but the only problem I am facing is that I am not able to stop this communication.

For example, I send 5 bytes of data, and in response I am expecting 3 bytes of data. I get this data but after that I don't see any stop condition. And due to that I cannot send further data to my slave device.

I am checking my results with logic analyzer, and in logic analyzer it shows unknown after receiving 3 bytes. (Images attached).

It seems like I am not properly starting and stopping the I2C communication.

The code I have written is given below:

```
#include <msp430.h>


char TXData[5] = { 0x5A, 0xCF, 0x00 };        //Data to be transmitted
//unsigned char TXData[] = { 0x5A, 0x40, 0x09, 0x80, 0x04, 0x00, 0x22, 0x03, 0x41, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04, 0xE5, 0xEF }; // GetMemory APDU
//unsigned char TXData[] = { 0x5A, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x80, 0x04, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0A, 0xEE, 0x07 }; // CreateSession APDU
//unsigned char TXData[] = { 0x5A, 0x00, 0x16, 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x10, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x96, 0x54, 0x53, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA8, 0xC8 }; // GetVersion APDU
volatile unsigned char RXData[3];                                     // To save the received data
unsigned char SlaveAddress = 0x48;                          // slave address
volatile unsigned char TXByteCtr;
volatile unsigned char TxByteCnt = 0;
volatile unsigned char RxByteCnt = 0;
unsigned char Rx;                                                 // To enable reception
void Transmit(void);
void Recieve(void);
short crc_ret;
//short final;
unsigned short crc16_x25(char* pData, int length)
{
    int i;
    unsigned short wCrc = 0xffff;
    while (length--) {
        wCrc ^= *(unsigned char *)pData++ << 0;
        for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
            wCrc = wCrc & 0x0001 ? (wCrc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : wCrc >> 1;
    }
    return wCrc ^ 0xffff;
}
int main(void)
{

    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
    //while(1);
    // Configure GPIO
    P8OUT |= BIT0;                                          // Clear P8.0 output latch
    P8DIR |= BIT0;
    P7SEL0 |= BIT0 | BIT1;
    P7SEL1 &= ~(BIT0 | BIT1);


    // Disable the GPIO power-on default high-impedance mode to activate
    // previously configured port settings
    PM5CTL0 &= ~LOCKLPM5;

    // Configure USCI_B2 for I2C mode
    UCB2CTLW0 |= UCSWRST;                                        // put eUSCI_B in reset state
    UCB2CTLW0 |= UCMODE_3 | UCMST | UCSSEL__SMCLK;              // I2C master mode, SMCLK
    UCB2BRW = 0x8;                                              // baudrate = SMCLK / 8
    UCB2CTLW0 &= ~UCSWRST;                                      // clear reset register
    UCB2IE |= UCTXIE0 | UCNACKIE | UCRXIE0;                     // transmit, Receive and NACK interrupt enable

    crc_ret = crc16_x25(TXData, (sizeof(TXData) - 2));   // Calling CRC function

    TXData[3] = (char)crc_ret;
    TXData[4] = (char)((crc_ret&0xFF00)>>8);

    while(1)
    {
       __delay_cycles(2000);                                    // Delay between transmissions
        UCB2I2CSA = SlaveAddress;                               // configure slave address
        TXByteCtr = 1;                                          // Load TX byte counter
        Transmit();                                             //Implementing the transmit function
        __delay_cycles(2000);
        Rx = 1;
        Recieve();                                              //Implementing the receive function
        __delay_cycles(2000);

    }
}

#pragma vector = EUSCI_B2_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B2_ISR(void)

{

   switch(__even_in_range(UCB2IV, USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG))
    {
        case USCI_NONE:          break;                             // Vector 0: No interrupts
        case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:   break;                                 // Vector 2: ALIFG
        case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:                                    // Vector 4: NACKIFG
            UCB2CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;                                   // resend start if NACK
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:  break;                                 // Vector 6: STTIFG
        case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:  break;                                 // Vector 8: STPIFG
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG3:  break;                                 // Vector 10: RXIFG3
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG3:  break;                                 // Vector 12: TXIFG3
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG2:  break;                                 // Vector 14: RXIFG2
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG2:  break;                                 // Vector 16: TXIFG2
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG1:  break;                                 // Vector 18: RXIFG1
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG1:  break;                                 // Vector 20: TXIFG1
        case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG0:                                     // Vector 22: RXIFG0

            if (Rx < 3)                                          // Check RX byte counter
            {
                RXData[RxByteCnt]= UCB2RXBUF;                       // Load TX buffer
                RxByteCnt++;
                Rx++;                                        // Decrement TX byte counter
                __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);               // Exit LPM0
            }
            else
            {
                UCB2CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;                               // I2C stop condition
                UCB2IFG &= ~UCRXIFG;                                // Clear USCI_B2 RX int flag
                __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);               // Exit LPM0
            }
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG0:                                     // Vector 24: TXIFG0


            if (TXByteCtr < (sizeof(TXData) + 1))                    // Check TX byte counter
            {
                UCB2TXBUF = TXData[TxByteCnt];                       // Load TX buffer
                TxByteCnt++;
                TXByteCtr++;                                        // Decrement TX byte counter
                __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);               // Exit LPM0
            }
            else
            {
                TxByteCnt = 0;

                UCB2CTLW0 |= UCTXSTP;                               // I2C stop condition
                UCB2IFG &= ~UCTXIFG;                                // Clear USCI_B2 TX int flag
                __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);               // Exit LPM0
            }
            break;
        case USCI_I2C_UCBCNTIFG: break;                              // Vector 26: BCNTIFG
        case USCI_I2C_UCCLTOIFG: break;                             // Vector 28: clock low timeout
        case USCI_I2C_UCBIT9IFG: break;                             // Vector 30: 9th bit
        default: break;
    }
}


void Transmit(void)
{
    while (UCB2CTLW0 & UCTXSTP);                            // Ensure stop condition got sent
    UCB2CTLW0 |= UCTR | UCTXSTT;                            // I2C TX, start condition
    __bis_SR_register(GIE);                     // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts
                                                            // Remain in LPM0 until all data
                                                            // is TX'd

}

void Recieve(void)
{

    while (UCB2CTLW0 & UCTXSTP);                            // Ensure stop condition got se
    UCB2CTLW0 &= ~UCTR;
    UCB2CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT;

    __bis_SR_register(GIE);                     // Enter LPM0 w/ interrupts//start condition;
                                                   // I2C stop condition
    UCB2CTLW0 &= ~UCTXSTP;

    //UCB2IFG &= ~UCRXIFG;


}
```

And the transmitted and received data is also attached:
[image: 5 bytes of data I am transmitting]

[image: 3 bytes of received data]

You can see in the received data, that after 3 bytes, there is written "unknown". Due to this unknown thing, I am not able to send further data.

I shall be very thankful if someone can help me out in this.

Thank you

Comment: There are many different MSP430 models. Which one are you using?

Comment: Do you want to use LPM or not? If yes, why are you waking up before all bytes have been handled?

Comment: I am using MSP430FR5994. 
No, I don't want to use LPM. And I tried replacing these with _enable_interrupts() and _disable_interrupts(), but still it gives the same result.

Comment: The example programs use sleep mode and wakeups to wait for events. Without LPM, you to wait for such events with an explicit loop.

Comment: Yes I checked in the example programs, if I use LPM, then I am having the problem stated above. Maybe I am not using it properly. But you can see in the code, that I am entering and leaving LPM at the same positions both in the transmit and in the receive functions and the ISRs. But in case of transmit, it is working properly. But not in receive. If you see in the ISR of receiving part, then i tried putting the break point in the "else" part of if-else condition, and the compiler is not executing that part.

Comment: Why are you putting in wakeups when you do not want to use LPM?

Comment: Then in ISR, should I write _bic_SR_register_on_exit(GIE) ?

Comment: No, that would not make sense. LPM makes sense the most when you are using interrupt handlers; if you do not want to use LPM, then you should not use interrupt handlers (i.e., no enable interrupts at all), and wait for events by polling the modules' interrupt flags.

Comment: Ok good. And when I use LPM, then in my code, I have two functions Transmit() and Receive(). In both these functions, After starting i2c communication(UCB2CTLW0 |= UCTXSTT), I am using _bis_SR_register, means I am getting into the ISR. Right? Now, In the Transmit ISR everything working fine, it is transmitting 5 bytes, then STOP. But in the Receive  ISR, I don't know what is the mistake here, that it is not stopping this communication. As you said, I am waking up before all bytes have been handled. But it receives all bytes. IN above case there are 3 bytes.

Comment: The "exit LPM" code is executed after the first byte is received.

Comment: This question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. You should try to learn about microprocessor architecture, interrupt programming, MSP430 hardware, and I²C face-to-face, or from some tutorials or books.